# Convert String date to milliseconds

Tags: android

How I can convert String  dd/MM/yyyy to miliseconds ?

I enter 03/09/15 and I get number "-"   -61651......  is normal ?

```
public Long Func1(String givenDateString){
    //String givenDateString = "Tue Apr 23 16:08:28 GMT+05:30 2013";
    //SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    long timeInMilliseconds=0;
    try {
        Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
        timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
        System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return timeInMilliseconds;
}
```

Comment: How can you convert a date to milliseconds?  Are you asking to get a DateTime in epoch milliseconds (milliseconds from 1970)?  Otherwise you need a timespan.

Comment: if so, the code seems to be correct. I tried it myself, Func1("09/03/2015") would return 1425884400000, which is correct.

Comment: It appears that you wish to delete your question.  That would be preferable to obliterating it via edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is working as intended -- you're just giving it incorrect data. You specify your format as `dd/MM/yyyy` (emphasis `yyyy`), yet you're giving it a 2-digit year. That would be interpreted as the literal year `15`. Since the milliseconds value is time since January 1, 1970, you would expect a significant negative value for the year 15.

Either modify your format to use a 2-digit year (`dd/MM/yy`) or more preferably pass in `03/09/2015`.

Answer (score 0):

`Date.getTime()` method returns the number of milliseconds between midnight of January 1, 1970 and the specified date, which is the Unix time.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

=-=-=-=-= Edited =-=-=-=-=

if you need only the millisecond, you would use the `Date.getTime()%1000`.

Comment: not is a solution, I need pass data with this format dd/MM/yyyy and return miliseconds about this data String, to compare with datecurrent